# react-native upload file from local storage to firebase Network Request failed

Tags: blob, react-native, firebase-storage

i have an audio recording in my android local storage , i want to upload it to firebase storage , i am getting path with react native fs

```
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test3.wav';
this._uploadFile(path)
```

uploading method

```
 _uploadFile = async (imageuri) => {

    try {   const response2 = await fetch(imageuri);
               const blob = await response2.blob();

      const ref = firebase.storage().ref("humza").child(new Date().getTime() + "");    
      const task = ref.put(blob);    
      task.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
               snapshot =>
                    console.log(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100),
                error => {
                      console.log("error", error);
                      return error;
        },
               result => {
                      console.log("result", task.snapshot.metadata);
                      return result;
        });
    }          catch (e) {   
                      console.log(e); }    
               }
```

gives me an error

```
 LOG  [TypeError: Network request failed]
```

is there a way to upload to firebase from react native ?
Any Alternate solution for Audio Streaming app is also Appreciated